# Parse a JSON string in Puppet

Tags: json, puppet

I am trying to parse a very simple json file in Puppet manifest but am struggling with it.

Following sample Puppet manifest works but it only prints the entries in the json file

```
include stdlib
$hash = loadjson('/tmp/file.json')
notify("$hash")
```

JSON file

```
{
  "output": {
    "message": "This is the entire value",
    "return_value": "0"
  }
}
```

I want to be able to assign "message" to variable "$message" and "return_value" to variable "$return_value"

Comment: You don't need to include stdlib since you are using a custom function from it which is automatically loaded during pluginsync. In fact, including it here does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would write:

```
  $hash = loadjson('/tmp/file.json')
  $message      = $hash['output']['message']
  $return_value = $hash['output']['return_value']
  notice("$message, $return_value")
```

Or more concisely:

```
  $hash = loadjson('/tmp/file.json')
  [$message, $return_value] = $hash['output']
  notice("$message, $return_value")
```

As mentioned in a comment above, there is no actual need for `include stdlib` here.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. what is the difference between loadjson and parsejson ? Where can I find additional documentation on these ?

Comment: Both documented here https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib  Looks like one expects a JSON string, the other a JSON file.